# Is there a way to know when the ThreadPool is done?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have code that is calling an API and logging the response. Inside the response is a possible uri for another API, which I also need to call. I am trying to do this on multiple threads. If I use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` this works great. Close to 5000 calls in under a minute. What I am trying to figure out is how can my main thread know when all the other threads are done.

Here's an example of what I've got.

```
private void Initiate(string initialUri)
{
    CallEndpoint(initialUri);
}

private void CallEndpoint(string endpointUri)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(BeginCall, new object[] { endpointUri });
}

private void BeginCall(object state)
{
    object[] array = state as object[];
    string endpointUri = array[0].ToString();
/*
Logic that calls the api, saves the response and checks the response for another uri to call
*/

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri)
{
    CallEndpoint(uri);
}
```

This works great but I need my UI to know when this is done. Threading is not my strong suit. I've googled this a lot and I'm probably going about this wrong. Appreciate any help.

Comment: IMHO Use a different type of queue so you control how many concurrent requests to make. eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library or https://saigontechnology.com/blog/implement-producerconsumer-patterns-using-channel-in-c

Comment: Are you scraping a website?

Comment: You could use `Interlocked.Increment` (/`Decrement`) to count active threads. Wrap the up/down calls in some functions and test whether the count drops to zero

Comment: Do you queue work on the `ThreadPool` from the main thread only, or other threads can queue work too? More importantly, is there a definitive point in time when you are absolutely sure that no more work is going to be queued on the `ThreadPool`?

Comment: Why use the threadpool directly anyway, why not just use tasks or `Parallel.ForEachAsync`

Answer (score 2):

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` is a fairly low level API for the thread pool. If you want to know when work items complete you need to provide your own synchronization. The most trivial way would be to use `Interlocked.Increment` before queuing the item, and `Interlocked.Decrement` when it is done. If the count reaches zero you could send a message to the main thread.

But I would probably recommend using some higher level API. The best solution will likely depend on your exact requirements. Some possibilities are:

- Task.Run + Task.WaitAll
- BlockingCollection with one or more threads calling GetConsumingEnumerable
- Parallel.Foreach loop
- [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

Comment: As an addition - `TaskCompletionSource + Task.WhenAll/WaitAll` can also be used.